# how to resize different div's on drag? in ionic anjular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic app that will look like below image. there will be three div's that will re-size themselves when the red circle is dragged on screen. all div will resize according to the placement of that red circle.

[Concept image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVXRK.png)

Comment: Please provide your actual code instead of an image. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for example for further help - How to ask a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know your actual template, but this could be a starting point:

**template.html** - your view

```
...
<ion-content on-drag="resize()"></ion-content>
...
```

**template.js** - your controller

```
...
$scope.resize = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
}
...
```

Do not forget to inject the `$ionicScrollDelegate` service to your controller dependencies...

Comment: i am using tabs template in ionic.